# Java - Handle data type mismatch and continue program

Tags: java, exception

I am running a method that takes a (char,double,char) and returns a double or a string.

I an running into an error when it returns the strings. How can I handle the string and continue the program?

I do have a try catch, and it is catching the string but the program stops.

Thanks a bunch.

All I have of the code,

```
public class Function
{
   public static double shippingCost(char packageType, double weight, char customerType)
   {
   .................
   .................
   }

}
```

*It is not meant to be good design. It is for error testing.

Comment: `returns a double. However it also returns a string at times`, Could you clarify this point? Provide an example.

Comment: A code sample would be very helpful since it's hard to understand what your problem is...

Comment: Nope, you can only return one kind of thing.  You can make it a java.lang.Object and return either java.lang.String or java.lang.Double, but it's not a good abstraction at all.  There's no reason to return a shipping cost as either a double or a String.  I'd write a Money class and return that.

Comment: I think he was trying to overload the function by return type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You possibly can return Object from the method (which will allow you to return a String or a Double). In the code where you call this methods, you would then need to detect what type of Object the returned result is, so that you can handle it properly.

Answer (score 2):

The code logic must be split up. One method returns double, the other returns String. The same thing should be applied to parameters. Only what is always used inside method body should be passed. Code clean, avoid ambiguity.